# Talk about Grandpa's weird talk: Who are these folks?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

"These guys are strange" exclaimed Grandpa

"Why?" I opened my mouth. Too late.

> "They constantly talk about only one country and only one sport-- boring sport if you ask me, and, get this, only one drink!"
>
> "who?" I shouldn't have.
>
> "and why in the world would you discuss only one month? Constantly?  You tell me"

I couldn't. Maybe you can.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These folks are:

> The people at NATO

Since:

> Among the codewords in their [phonetic alphabet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) only one is a country (INDIA), only one is a sport (GOLF), only one is a drink (WHISKEY*), and only one is a month (NOVEMBER).

My advice - perhaps you should:

> Take up dancing - with both FOXTROT and TANGO, you'll have twice as much to talk about! ;-)

<sub>* Of course this assumes:</sub>

> <sub>We ignore 'Tango' as a brand name of soft drink...!</sub>

Comment: Bravo!  An excellent answer, to an excellent question xD

Comment: And only one Shakespeare play, though it gets 2 mentions.

Comment: given the he's grouchy, we can guess grandpa's name

Answer (score 3):

These folk could be:

> Santa's elves!

Since they:

> Only talk about:
>  The North Pole (which they consider a country, their country). Sure they deliver gifts all over the world to every country, but they only *talk* about the goings on at the North Pole.
>  Reindeer Games (Rudolf wasn't allowed to participate until that fateful night).
>  Milk (mainly who gave Santa a glass and who didn't).
>  And December, of course, is the one and only focus all year round.